# SharePoint Foundation 2013 Manual Refresh List

Tags: 2013, web-part, sharepoint-foundation

I have a SharePoint 2013 custom list with thousands of data in it. So under the Web Part Properties -> AJAX Options on the list web part, I have enabled Asynchronous Update and Show Manual Refresh Button.

Now my problem is when I click on Next Page on the list 2 times, and click on the Manual Refresh Button, it gives an empty list. But when I click on the Next Page only once, and click the Manual Refresh Button, it just works fine.

Has anybody encountered this problem?

Comment: Something in the dev tools console? Sounds like a javascript problem to me.

Comment: additional to what Max stated, do you have any JS includes in your master page that might cause any conflict?

Comment: I don't have any JS includes in my master page.  However, I have added in some CSS to remove the left navigation side bar.  I found a workaround to this problem yesterday by checking the Server Render under the Miscellaneous tab of the web part but it hid the views that I have created for the list.